# Can't get a wordpress menu in order

Tags: wordpress, menu

Created 2 menus. One for header and one for footer (2 extra items). The one for header gets ordered perfectly well. And i can't get one for the footer ordered via admin panel. Any thoughts why it could be happening and how i can fix it?

Could it be because of css caret?

```
<nav class="special-nav">
<ul class="menu">
    <li><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer-menu' ) ); ?></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

css

```
.menu {
float: left; /* or not */
list-style: none;
margin: 0; padding: 0;
overflow: hidden; /* $shame use a clear fix instead */

border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.02); /* just so you can see */
}

.menu ul {
list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
float: left;
}

.menu li.current_page_item a {

}

.menu a {
position: relative; /* so you can position things absolutely to its borders */
display: block; /* to give the shape */
padding: 1em;
text-decoration: none;
 }

.menu a:after {
content: "\0020"; /* because you need something in this pseudo element for it to work */
position: absolute; /* to position based on parent */
top: 0;
left: 50%; /* to center-ish */
margin-left: -5px; /* basically half your triangle width  for further centering */

/* triangle */
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px 7.5px 0 7.5px;
border-color: transparent;

transition: all .3s linear; /* or not */
}

.menu a:hover:after {
border-color: #4f69bf transparent transparent transparent;
transition: all .1s linear;
}
```

screenshot here
http://s020.radikal.ru/i710/1401/61/0c70fd0f3a60.jpg

Comment: source code? screen shots? we aren't omnipetent here 7;^)

Comment: My bad.  code and screenshot added.

Comment: Did you try to order from admin?

Comment: yep. that's why I'm here